# How do i find mongodb collection and update multiple fields using pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

This is the code snippet

```py
send = mongo.db.subscription
send.find().update({'$set':{'status': "expired"}})
```

this is the output i get

```
send.find().update({'$set':{'status': "expired"}})
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is:

```
send.update_many({<filter_condition>}, {'$set':{'status': "expired"}})
```